# passing $event to ng-click but event is undefined

Tags: angularjs

In my controller, upon a click event, I add a directive to the page, which is going to be able to call `controllerFunc`

```
$scope.addDirective = function(e, instance){
   $scope.instance = instance;
   $(e.currentTarget.parentElement).append($compile('<my-directive myfunc="controllerFunc($event)" mydata={{instance}}/>')($scope));
}
```

In my directive, I set it up so that controllerFunc gets called on a click event (via myfunc: &), and I try to pass the click event via `$event`

```
app.directive('myDirective',function(){
        return {
         restrict: 'AE',
         scope: {
           mydata: '@',
           myfunc: "&"

         },
         template: '<div class="row"><div class="col-4" ng-click="myfunc($event)"></div></div>',
         link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
             //ommitted

         }

        }
}
```

When I click the relevant div, `controllerFunc` gets called in the controller but the event is said to be `undefined`.

```
 $scope.controllerFunc = function(e){
       //called on the click event but e is undefined
 }
```

Is there a way to pass the event with `ng-click` in this situation (i.e. where I've added a template to the dom with an ng-click event? It seems like it should work (since the click event triggers the function) but there's no event in `controllerFunc`

Comment: try this  `ng-click="myfunc( { $event: $event} )`. it should work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is, inside of your controller function, note the name of the argument

```
'<my-directive myfunc="controllerFunc($event)" mydata={{instance}}/>')($scope));
```

It's currently "$event", this isn't a function that uses the $event keyword, it's just a function that has an argument, and you have to provide it. I would change $event to event for clarity.

Now, after you've done that, you can go to your directive, and in the template for your directive, you're setting the ng-click param like so

```
template: '<div class="row"><div class="col-4" ng-click="myfunc($event)"></div></div>',
```

That ng-click is going to invoke the & function, but in order to bind it to the proper parameter, you have to use slightly different syntax, and match the name of the param it's supposed to match, so

```
ng-click="myfunc($event)"
```

becomes

```
ng-click="myfunc({event: $event})"
```

That's assuming you've changed the original $event to event.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about div element, but if you are executing ng-click against an anchor () element, you may be experiencing this issue. To prevent it, you should set its onclick property with event.preventDefault() lick this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault()" ng-click="Cancel($event)">Cancel</a>
```

This will prevent the navigation to the link before ng-click gets a chance to execute.

Thank you.

Comment: Better to preventDefault() in the controller, it makes the dom clearer and the maintainable code if your template change.

Comment: cancel($event) in the view, $event.preventDefault() or return false in the code function

Comment: I don't understand, perhaps a code snippet will help.
Thank you.

Comment: I think making the controller function return `false` is the cleanest solution if you are not going to use the event, no need to pass the event just to call preventDefault on it.